# How to turn on pages automatically with Speak Screen in ePub Reader

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, epub3, ebook-reader

I have developed iOS reader with UIWebview. I am able to use speak screen with my ePub reader. It speaks the text content.
Problem is Speak screen is not automatically turn on next page for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Update ios version or  delete then re-downloaded the app.